# Is there a book/guide for implementing a conditional restart system

Tags: lisp, scheme, condition-system

I'm interesting in learning more about conditional restart systems and how they work. I'm not sure where to start. I've been looking at source code but was wondering if there was any higher level guides available.

Comment: The accepted answer is how to use and how it works, not how to implement it (since your favorite lisp don't support it)

Comment: Its impolite to change it right? I've given my upvote to @rainer anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might like to read the chapter in Practical Common Lisp

[19. Beyond Exception Handling: Conditions and Restarts](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/beyond-exception-handling-conditions-and-restarts.html)

An discussion on LtU, check out the comments:

[Common Lisp Exception Handling](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1544)

An explanation illustrating the stack state:

[What's a condition system and why do you want one?](http://axisofeval.blogspot.com/2011/04/whats-condition-system-and-why-do-you.html)

and an example with links to further references:

[Simple restarts example by Paul Gresham](http://gertm.blogspot.com/2009/04/conditions-restarts-and-great-people.html)

And a video tutorial by Patrick Stein

[Tutorial: Introduction to Conditions and Restarts](http://nklein.com/?s=restarts)

Comment: @zcaudate +1 for the PCL chapter 19 reference.  That one helped things “click” for me.

Comment: Nice, I'm a fan of Manuel Simoni's blog, a lot of interesting PLT stuff on there :)

Answer (score 9):

Kent Pitman: Condition System

http://www.nhplace.com/kent/CL/Revision-18.txt

Kent Pitman: Condition System, Sample Implementation

http://www.nhplace.com/kent/CL/Revision-18.lisp.txt

Kent Pitman: Exceptional Situations In Lisp

http://www.nhplace.com/kent/Papers/Exceptional-Situations-1990.html

Kent Pitman: Condition Handling in the Lisp Language Family

http://www.nhplace.com/kent/Papers/Condition-Handling-2001.html

Taylor Campbell: Restarting conditions

http://mumble.net/~campbell/proposals/restart.text

SRFI 34: Exception Handling for Programs

http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-34/srfi-34.html